# how to get specific numeric value from a web table cell using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

For example, I am having a final cell from the web table that reads, **deducted amount: Rs.15,892 from your linked account.**

Now I want to extract only the numeric value, which is 15892 for further calculations.
How can I go about it. I searched and tried the following.

1. Spitting based on space and getting the values based on index - didn't worked
2. Replacing the other stuff except the numeric value with empty spaces. - that too didn't work.

My idea is to get only the number.

Comment: Can you get the data extracted like you showed "Rs. 15,892" and then just use the programming language to remove non digit chars ?

Comment: @AnandSrireddy Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet:

```
String accountInfoMsg = "deducted amount: Rs.15,892 from your linked account.";
int amountExtracted = Integer.parseInt(accountInfoMsg.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found a solution to this however, still posting it so that others who are facing similar issue can get help!!

You can try this :

```java
String accountInfoMsg = "deducted amount: Rs.15,892 from your linked account.";
String digits = accountInfoMsg.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
System.out.println(digits);
```